# WinRT replace colour in BitmapImage with another

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

I've been looking to do the following:

- Replace a `Colour` in a `Bitmap`, with a **Different** `Colour`.

After a bit of reading, i gather that this might be possible using `WriteableBitmap`.

I haven't a clue about `Bitmap/Image` processing, so i am not sure how this class can be used to achieve my requirement.

The following would be appreciated:

**Links to usefull articles** which would give me enough understanding
    to develop a solution of my own.

Comment: At least show a tiny bit of effort man.

Comment: For example, you want to replace all the red pixels (RGB = 255, 0, 0) with blue pixels, is that right?

Comment: I actually want to treat a particular colour as transparent. Is that possible? If not I want to change the hex colour from #0A59C2 to #F4EED6.

Comment: In what is this related to async?

Comment: At the time of posting this question, i thought that the solution would leverage some async features. Truth be told the only time async was used was when i assigned the edited bitmap for UI binding, using the SetSourceAsync method as well as WriteAsync for writing the changed bitmap pixel data. I've subsequently removed the winrt-async tag from this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library. Get the Pixels array of the picture which holds all the pixels as Int32. Get the RGB values for each pixel using

```
var c = inputPixels[i];
var a = (byte)(c >> 24);
var r = (byte)(c >> 16);
var g = (byte)(c >> 8);
var b = (byte)(c);
```

Check if that is the color you want. If it is, change that color to another color using new argb byte values

```
resultPixels[i] = (a << 24) | 
                  (r << 16) | 
                  (g << 8) | 
                  b;
```

Read more about image processing in a great tutorial here

[PicFx – Windows Phone Picture Effects Application – Part 1](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/PicFx--Windows-Phone-Picture-Effects-Application--Part-1)

[PicFx – Windows Phone Picture Effects Application – Part 2](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/PicFx--Windows-Phone-Picture-Effects-Application--Part-2)